# Should my ViewModel's constructor populate the ViewModel's data?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

Should my ViewModel encapsulate the Services needed to populate it?

Currently I'm doing it as follows:

```
public PartialViewResult Companies(SearchViewModel search)
{
    search.Summary = _entitySearchService.GetSearchDataSummary(search.SearchExpression);
    search.PagedCompanies = _companyService.GetPagedEntities<Company>(search.SearchExpression);

    return PartialView(search);
}
```

But what if `SearchViewModel` populated these properties in its constructor? I could get StructureMap to pass in the interfaces to the services. Would that be a valid use of a ViewModel?

Answer (score 3):

check this amazing video [Put your controller on a diet](http://www.viddler.com/explore/mvcconf/videos/1/). It covers the things which you are looking for and even more.

Answer (score 1):

No, don't do that because your going to have repetition for the same type of properties in different viewmodels, look at the sample asp.net MVC project from here: http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com